# How to change the Bootstrap pagination page-item active border color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are a few posts on the subject but nothing seems to work with the latest Bootstrap.

Here is my css:

```
.pagination .page-link { background-color:#1d1d1d !important; border: 1px solid grey; }
.pagination { color:black !important; }
.pagination .active { background-color:white !important; color:red !important; } 
.pagination > .active > a , .pagination > .active > a:hover, .pagination > .active > a:focus { background-color: grey !important; border-color: grey !important; }
```

Everything is fine except the active page... how can I change the colors of the text (now white), the background (now black) and most important the default border (blue)?

Comment: have you check the class by using dev tools ?

Comment: @Sfili_81 thank you... i did but was on the wrong line... the css handle is .page-item.active .page-link and it works!